# Did I break my computer? Stuck on "Please remove the installation medium, then reboot"

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu. Everything worked fine. Then it asked me to restart the computer. I did. But forgot to pull out the boot stick. So I got on a screen saying the message " Please remove the installation medium, then reboot".

I tried pressing enter that didn't work.. then I entered "exit" and "reboot". This had no effect at all.

How to proceed? Is the computer broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the LiveUSB, force a power off, then power back on. If the newly installed OS will not boot, then reboot from the LiveUSB and reinstall.

Comment: How do I force a power off? I removed the stick as soon as I saw the message. But the battery is built in and the power button does nothing.

Comment: If there's no way to force it, pull the power cord, turn the brightness up (to burn more power) and let it shut down when it runs out of battery.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum Typically, holding down the power button for 10 seconds forces a power off.

Comment: Everything is working.. I had to press the button for 15 seconds.  Thank you for taking your time.